# How to display things such as username when youve extended the Django User Model in admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-admin

so I expanded on the Django User Model and this is what I currently have:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, related_name = 'StudentProfile', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    school = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    #replies = models.ManyToManyField()


class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, related_name = 'TeacherProfile', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    school = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    head_of_subject = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    headmaster = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    #reviews = models.ManyToManyField()

class SchoolProfile(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
    identification_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique = True)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(TeacherProfile, blank = True)
```

I am now setting up the admin.py and I was wondering how i could display things such as the users first, last, and username?

This is what I have tried, however it has not worked.

```
class StudentProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["user.username", "school"]

    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile

class TeacherProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["user.username", "school"]

    class Meta:
        model = TeacherProfile

class SchoolProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["school_name", "identification_code"]

    class Meta:
        model = SchoolProfile

admin.site.register(StudentProfile, StudentProfileAdmin)

admin.site.register(TeacherProfile, TeacherProfileAdmin)
admin.site.register(SchoolProfile, SchoolProfileAdmin)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function to the modeladmin to return the related user's username

```
class StudentProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["username", "school"]

    def username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username

    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
```

Edit: It also works with functions defined on the model. So you could add the `username` function to the model if you'd  like to keep your admin.py cleaner.

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, related_name = 'StudentProfile',
                                on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    school = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    @propery
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: legend! Thanks for your help